# MATLAB - Eval function and printing many plots

Tags: matlab

The variable is a `32x8x40940` double matrix. Here's an example of what I want to accomplish:

```
plot(squeeze(variableName(1,1,:)))
plot(squeeze(variableName(1,2,:)))
plot(squeeze(variableName(1,3,:)))
```

... repeat in a loop

```
plot(squeeze(variableName(2,1,:)))
```

... repeat the sequence above

**except** that I want to save the plots instead of just generating all of them. I also want them in image form (e.g. png) for I can organize them using another software that I have.

The following [`eval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) function was an example that I was given, but the documentation is lacking examples for me to use in this case. I want to have it automatically save the plots to a specific area in my directory.

```
eval( [ 'print( ''-dpng'', ''..\folder\another_Folder_', num2str( var ), '.png'')' ] ); 
% 'var' being iteration number within loop
```

Any ideas?

Comment: D you know how to write for loops? This is an easily solvable problem with for loops and with the builtin Matlab saveas function. More info on saveas: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you should avoid using `eval` for a myriad of security, readability, and general good coding reasons reasons. 
Notes [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/), [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/), and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html)

If you want to do save the looped figures, consider using the `saveas` function in Matlab. From the [help](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html),

```
x = [2 4 7 2 4 5 2 5 1 4];
bar(x);
saveas(gcf,'Barchart.png')
```

The `gcf` is the current figure that is open in matlab.

In your case, once you write a loop, you can assign these to an array or some other data structure before using the saveas command. You can also append the counter to the filename (make sure to convert the integer to a string so that `strcat` doesn't fail.

```
y[loopcounter]=plot(squeeze(variableName(1,1,:)))
saveas(y[loopcounter],strcat('file',str(loopcounter),'.extension_format'))
```